# Display Last Login in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display user last login in WordPress but the function is capturing the latest login, whereas I would prefer to display the login before the latest login time.

My snippet is as following. Hope someone to guide me out. Thanks!

```html
 public static function last_login( $user_login, $users ){

      global $show_login_records;

       //get/update user meta 'when_last_login' on login and add time() to it.
       update_user_meta( $users->ID, 'when_last_login', time() );

       //get and update user meta 'when_last_login_count' on login for # of login counts. Thanks to Jarryd Long (@jarrydlong) from Code Cabin (@code_cabin) for the assistance
       $wll_count = get_user_meta( $users->ID, 'when_last_login_count', true );

       if( $wll_count === false ){
         update_user_meta($users->ID, 'when_last_login_count', 1);
       } else {
         $wll_new_value = intval($wll_count);
         $wll_new_value = $wll_new_value + 1;

         update_user_meta($users->ID, 'when_last_login_count', $wll_new_value);
       }
       if( $show_login_records == true ){
       $args = array(
          'post_title'    => $users->data->display_name . __( ' has logged in at ', 'when-last-login' ) . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => $users->ID,
          'post_type'     => 'wll_records'
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

      }

        $wll_settings = get_option( 'wll_settings' );

        if( isset( $wll_settings['record_ip_address'] ) && $wll_settings['record_ip_address'] == 1 ){

          // call function to anonymize here.
          $ip = When_Last_Login::wll_get_user_ip_address();

          if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wll_user_ip_address', $ip );
          }
          
            update_user_meta( $users->ID, 'wll_user_ip_address', $ip );
        }

        do_action( 'wll_logged_in_action', array( 'login_count' => $wll_new_value, 'user' => $users ), $wll_settings );

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you. It works with two user meta's  `current_login, last_login`.Lets see the code.

```
//function for setting the last login
function set_last_login($login) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
    $curent_login_time = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'current_login', true);
    //add or update the last login value for logged in user
    if(!empty($curent_login_time)){
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', $curent_login_time );
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
    }else {
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
    }
}
```

This will helps you to save the current and last login times. you can write an get last time function to get last login time. Here is an article regarding the Last login [Click here](http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/12/how-to-set-user-last-login-date-and-time-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

I was using ACF with two custom fields to check the values of the login times. With the following code I managed to output through Shortcode

```html
/**
* Display last login time
*
*/
add_action('wp_login', 'set_last_login');
//function for setting the last login
function set_last_login($login) {
 $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
 $curent_login_time = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'current_login', true);
 //add or update the last login value for logged in user
 if(!empty($curent_login_time)){
  update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', $curent_login_time );
  update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
 }else {
  update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
  update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
 }
}



function lastlogin() {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
    'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    'format' => get_option( 'date_format' ).' '.get_option( 'time_format' )
  ), $atts, 'current_login' );
  $author_id = get_current_user_id();
  $last_login = get_field('last_login', 'user_'. $author_id);
  $offset = get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
  return $last_login;
}

/**
* Add Shortcode lastlogin
*
*/

add_shortcode('lastlogin','lastlogin');
```